# Regex expression not working - what am I missing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the number (`123`) from data written in the format `123:AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ` using Javascript.

Currently I have a regular expression `/^[0-9]*(?=\:)/` and using

```
var ABC = pattern.match(regex);
```

but I keep coming up empty handed. What is wrong with my expression?

Comment: What are `pattern` and `regex`? Because `"123:AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ".match(/^[0-9]*(?=\:)/)` works.

Comment: `'123:AB.CD.EF.GH.IJ'.match(/^[0-9]*(?=\:)/)` works just fine for me. Your problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry was very vague, pattern is just the text in the format I gave and regex is that regular expression defined using var regex = RegExp("^[0-9]*(?=\:)", "")

Comment: Try changing the `^` to a `\b` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could skip regex and use `pattern.split(':')[0]`.

Comment: I like this even better. It's good to avoid regexes if not doing complicated text processing.

Comment: Thanks and good answer. I really didnt want to pass another variable. Cheers out to everybody.

Comment: Nice. Sometimes simpler is better.

Comment: Thanks! I just really never get regexes, which makes me good at thinking of ways to avoid them...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var number = value.replace(/:.*/);   // where value is the "123:AB.CD.EF.GH.IH" string
```

Sometimes doing the same thing a different way will yeidl better result, I've found with regexs.

Answer (score 0):

Match returns an array. You might need `pattern.match(regex)[1]` where 1 is the matched string. You don't need the `(?=\:)` at the end. You will also need to specify what you are capturing.

Try this:

`regex = /^([0-9]*)/`

The parenthesis say what you want to match. Remember, match returns an array.  Use JSON.stringify() to find what you're getting. `JSON.stringify(ABC)`. JSON is supported on FF, Chrome, and Safari I believe.